# The debug doesn't find the error...strange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting crazy...there is an error in the scrip but I dont find it and, strange, also the debug of explorer doesn't find it!!

I cheked it a lot of time with the excercise but I am not able to find it.

```js
<script src="../_js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  
$('#gallery img').each(function(i) {
 var imgFile = $(this).attr('src');
 var preloadImage = new Image();
 var imgExt = /(\.\w{3,4}$)/;
 preloadImage.src = imgFile.replace(imgExt,'_h$1');
  
 $(this).hover(
  function() {
   $(this).attr('src', preloadImage.src);
  },
  function () {
  var currentSource=$(this).attr('src');
   $(this).attr('src', imgFile);
 }); // end hover
}); // end each
 
$('#gallery a').click(function(evt){
 evt.preventDefault();
 var imgPath = $(this).attr('href');

var oldImage = $('#photo img');
var newImage = $('<img src"' + imgPath +'">');
newImage.hide();
$('#photo').prepend(newImage);
newImage.fadeIn(1000);
oldImage.fadeOut(1000,function(){
 $(this).remove();
}); //end fadeout
});// end click
$('#gallery a:first').click();

}); // end ready
</script>
```

```css
<style>
#gallery {
 float: left;
 width: 90px;
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 border-right: white 1px dotted;
}
#gallery img {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
 border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
}
#photo {
 margin-left: 150px;
 position: relative;
}
#photo img {
 position: absolute;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Rollover Images</title>
<link href="../_css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
 <header>
    JAVASCRIPT <span class="amp">&amp;</span> jQUERY: THE&nbsp;MISSING&nbsp;MANUAL
 </header>
 <div class="content">
  <div class="main">
   <h1>Slideshow</h1>
   <div id="gallery"> <a href="../_images/large/slide1.jpg"><img src="../_images/small/slide1.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="golf balls"></a> <a href="../_images/large/slide2.jpg"><img src="../_images/small/slide2.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="rock wall"></a> <a href="../_images/large/slide3.jpg"><img src="../_images/small/slide3.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="old course"></a> <a href="../_images/large/slide4.jpg"><img src="../_images/small/slide4.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="tees"></a> <a href="../_images/large/slide5.jpg"><img src="../_images/small/slide5.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="tree"></a> <a href="../_images/large/slide6.jpg"><img src="../_images/small/slide6.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="ocean course"></a></div>
   <div id="photo"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <footer>
    <p>JavaScript &amp; jQuery: The Missing Manual, 3rd Edition, by <a href="http://sawmac.com/">David McFarland</a>. Published by <a href="http://oreilly.com/">O'Reilly Media, Inc</a>.</p>
 </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: I can see an error message when I run it ``"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }",`

Comment: although that may be because a bit of code is missing.

Comment: @franco Please can you check your code and ensure we have all the relevent parts. The error on the code snippet is indicating an extraneous } in your code.

Comment: How does the error surface if you cannot find it?

Comment: I posted all the code now sorry for before

Answer (score 0):

you have got syntax errors, i have corrected your syntax errors.
Here is the error free version:

```
$('#gallery a').click(function(evt){
evt.preventDefault();
var imgPath = $(this).attr('href');

var oldImage = $('#photo img');
var newImage = $('<img src"' + imgPath +'">');
newImage.hide();
$('#photo').prepend(newImage);
newImage.fadeIn(1000);
oldImage.fadeOut(1000,function(){
    $(this).remove();
}); //end fadeout
});// end click
$('#gallery a:first').click(function () {
  console.log("something")
});
```

you should post your html and expected behaviour if you want good answer.

Edit: after you updated your question, here you go with the solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#gallery img').each(function() {
           var imgFile = $(this).attr('src');
         var preloadImage = new Image();
         var imgExt = /(\.\w{3,4}$)/;
         preloadImage.src = imgFile.replace(imgExt,'_h$1');
        $(this).hover(
                function() {
                   $(this).attr('src', preloadImage.src);
                },
           function() {
                  $(this).attr('src', imgFile);
               }
            ); // end hover
          }); // end each
    $('#gallery a').click(function(evt) {
          evt.preventDefault();
           var imgPath = $(this).attr('href');
           var oldImage = $('#photo img');
           var newImage = $('<img src="' + imgPath + '">');
           newImage.hide();
           $('#photo').prepend(newImage);
           newImage.fadeIn(1000);
            oldImage.fadeOut(1000,function(){
                $(this).remove();
               }); // end fadeout
         }); // end click
     $('#gallery a:first').click();
}); // end ready
```

```css
#gallery {
 float: left;
 width: 90px;
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 border-right: white 1px dotted;
}
#gallery img {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
 border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
}
#photo {
 margin-left: 150px;
 position: relative;
}
#photo img {
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
        JAVASCRIPT <span class="amp">&amp;</span> jQUERY: THE&nbsp;MISSING&nbsp;MANUAL
    </header>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="main">
            <h1>Slideshow</h1>
            <div id="gallery">
                <a href="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=one&w=500&h=500"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=one&w=70&h=70" width="70" height="70" alt="golf balls"></a>
                <a href="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=two&w=500&h=500"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=two&w=70&h=70" width="70" height="70" alt="rock wall"></a>
                <a href="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=three&w=500&h=500"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=three&w=70&h=70" width="70" height="70" alt="old course"></a>
                <a href="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=four&w=500&h=500"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=four&w=70&h=70" width="70" height="70" alt="tees"></a>
                <a href="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=five&w=500&h=500"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=five&w=70&h=70" width="70" height="70" alt="tree"></a>
                <a href="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=six&w=500&h=500"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=six&w=70&h=70" width="70" height="70" alt="ocean course"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="photo"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>JavaScript &amp; jQuery: The Missing Manual, 3rd Edition, by <a href="http://sawmac.com/">David McFarland</a>. Published by
            <a href="http://oreilly.com/">O'Reilly Media, Inc</a>.</p>

    </footer>
</div>
```

And a link to the pen : https://codepen.io/faw/pen/MmoQRe?editors=1111

Comment: Well I floowed your suggestion and I posted all the code now...
But where did you find the errord??

Comment: and after you posted your code, i have updated my answer with working codepen link

Answer (score 0):

The `// end ready` part refers to `$(document).ready(function() {`.

Your code must be:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#gallery a').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var imgPath = $(this).attr('href');

    var oldImage = $('#photo img');
    var newImage = $('<img src"' + imgPath + '">');
    newImage.hide();
    $('#photo').prepend(newImage);
    newImage.fadeIn(1000);
    oldImage.fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $(this).remove();
    }); //end fadeout
  }); // end click
  $('#gallery a:first').click();
}); // end ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK Finally I found the error it was this line
var newImage = $('');
I missed the = after src

Thanks